# Mixing .NET 3.5 with 4/4.5 assemblies in the same solution/project

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-construction, clr

I have a solution that most projects are compiled in .net 4.5 (I use async and tasks).
There are couple of projects that need to be compiled in .net 3.5 since they use SDK that support only .net 3.5.
If my "Common" project is compiled in 4.5, and I have a project with target framework 3.5 that needs it, Is it possible to add reference to the Common ? (e.g my logger interface is at Common and i get it with DI).

Thanks.

Output:

```
could not be resolved because it was built against the ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" framework. This is a higher version than the currently targeted framework ".NETFramework,Version=v3.5".
```

Comment: What is stopping you from trying it?

Comment: Trying what ? i cant build this

Comment: Trying what you suggested in your question: "If my "Common" project is compiled in 4.5, and I have a project with target framework 3.5 that needs it, Is it possible to add reference to the Common ?"

Comment: I just did and i get error. I was wondering if there is a workaround to avoid getting this error. THIS IS the purpose of my questions, if there is a work-around for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the compiler tells you, it is not possible. You can try to split your "Common" library into two parts, one built for 4.5 and another for 3.5 framework.