# Project reference work-around .net 4.5 and .net 3.5

Tags: c#, .net, assemblies, clr

In continue for this thread:
[Mixing .NET 3.5 with 4/4.5 assemblies in the same solution/project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15463163/mixing-net-3-5-with-4-4-5-assemblies-in-the-same-solution-project)

I found a workaround:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/clr/thread/36b1a209-55d5-4323-91dc-0919ba2e1d03/

What it basically do, get my solution compile and determine each project under what CLR to run.
Does anyone see disadvantage to this ?
It builds the projects, on my 3rd party api that must run on .net 3.5, i explicity write on its App.config to run with CLR 2.0 and not 4.0

```
 <startup>
 <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>
 <!--<supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>-->
 </startup>
```

EDIT:
My main application is using .net 4.5 and C# 5 features. My 3rd party API is running on a child process (i start from main) and that process will connect to API that must be on 3.5 and CLR2. So i explicity define there to run as CLR2..

Comment: As long as you're not using any features that depend on v4+ then it should be fine

Comment: I think that question would depend on the platform in which your project is running.. for example if it's a web application, I have found so many issues with doing .Net 2.0 / 3.5 code that the same functionality was broken and didn't work in 4.0 I guess that this is something that you would really have to fully test in regards to regression in order to see if you are truly reaping the benifits `+1` good question by the way

Comment: It is SDK. the SDK should support .net 4.5 it is using advanced features C#5.. but the 3rd party API i am connected to is 3.5 and clr 2 a MUST.. they run on different processes btw

Comment: Why cannot you use AsyncBridge? That keeps all your projects in .NET 3.5 (though it has some limitations) http://omermor.github.com/AsyncBridge/ and https://www.simple-talk.com/blogs/2012/04/18/asyncbridge-write-async-code-for-net-3-5/

Answer (score 1):

Your configuration file will load .NET 2.0 runtime and it would fail at some point loading .NET4.5 components. You really want your app to run in .NET4.5 runtime and be able to load 3.5 components. You should try following config file.

```
<configuration>
    <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5"/>
    </startup>
</configuration>
```