# .Net 4.5 dll references in 3.5 project

Tags: .net, .net-3.5, .net-4.5

I am reworking a set of dll-library projects that is used by many older projects. The older projects are all built with target Framework 3.5.

Does this mean I can't build the dll-library for .Net 4.5 at all? Or does it just mean that I can't use language features > 3.5?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15549011/project-reference-work-around-net-4-5-and-net-3-5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, unfortunately you can't.

NET 4.5 uses a different compiler than .NET 3.5.

Comment: Thanks, but the other way around works right? Using 3.5 dlls in a 4.5 project?

Comment: Yes, newer versions of .NET can reference assemblies that are older version of .NET :)